# Can two items in a hashmap be in different locations but have the same hashcode?

Tags: data-structures, hash

Can two items in a hashmap be in different locations but have the same hashcode?

I'm new to hashing, and I've recently learned about hashmaps. I was wondering whether two objects with the same hashcode can possibly go to different locations in a hashmap?

I'm not completely sure and would appreciate any help

Comment: That depends entirely on what [collision-resolution method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) is being used (e.g. linear-probing vs chaining vs double-hashing, etc)

Answer (score 1):

As @Dai pointed out in the comments, this will depend on what kind of hash table you're using. (Turns out, there's a bunch of different ways to make a hash table, and no one data structure is "the" way that hash tables work!)

One of more common hash tables uses a strategy called *closed addressing*. In closed addressing, every item is mapped to a slot based on its hash code and stored with all other items that also end up in that slot. Lookups are then done by finding which bucket to look in, then inspecting all the items in that bucket. In that case, any two items with the same hash code will end up in the same bucket. (They can't literally occupy the same spot within that bucket, though.)

Another strategy for building hash tables uses an approach called *open addressing*. This is a family of different methods that are all based on the following idea. We require that each slot in the table store at most one element. As before, to do an insertion, we use the element's hash code to figure out which slot to put it in. If the slot is empty, great! We put the element there. If that slot is full, we can't put the item there. Instead, using some predictable strategy, we start looking at other slots until we find a free one, then put the item there. (The simplest way of doing this, *linear probing*, works by trying the next slot after the desired slot, then the next one, etc., wrapping around if need be.) In this system, since we can't store multiple items in the same spot, no, two elements with the same hash code don't have to (and in fact, can't!) occupy the same spot.

A more recent hashing strategy that's becoming more popular is *cuckoo hashing.* In cuckoo hashing, we maintain some small number of separate hash tables (typically, two or three), where each slot can only hold one item. To insert an element, we try placing it in the first table at a spot determined by its hash code. If that spot is free, great! We put the item there. If not, we kick out the item there and try putting that item in the next table. This process repeats until eventually everything comes to rest or we get caught in a loop. Like open addressing, this system prevents multiple items from being stored in the same slot, so two elements with the same hash code might go to different places. (There are variations on cuckoo hashing in which each table slot can store a fixed but small number of items, in which case you could have two items with the same hash code in the same spot. But it's not guaranteed.)

There are some other hashing schemes I didn't describe here. *FKS perfect hashing* works by using two layers of hash tables, along the lines of closed addressing, but periodically rebuilds the whole table to ensure that no one bucket is too overloaded. *Extendible hashing* uses a trie-like structure to grow overflowing buckets once they become too fully. *Hopscotch hashing* is a hybrid between linear probing and chained hashing and plays well with concurrency. But hopefully this gives you a sense of how the type of hash table you use influences the answer to your question!